# 'id(java.lang.String)' in 'org.openqa.selenium.By' cannot be applied to '(org.openqa.selenium.By)'

Tags: java, selenium, user-interface, automation

I am trying to use By in selenium as a String to get my element but it is giving me the error "'id(java.lang.String)' in 'org.openqa.selenium.By' cannot be applied to '(org.openqa.selenium.By)'"

Please assist me
Here is my code:

```
package adta;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;

public class LoginPage extends BasePage {

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
       super(driver);
    }

    public By getUserNameLocator(){
        return By.id("user-name");

    }


    public void open(){
        driver.get("https://www.saucedemo.com/");

    }
    public boolean isLoaded(){

        return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(getUserNameLocator()))).isDisplayed();

    }


    public void login(String username, String password) {
        driver.findElement(By.id(getUserNameLocator())).sendKeys(username);
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(password);
        driver.findElement(By.id("login-button")).click();
    }
}
```

I have tried to search for answers online but no luck

Comment: In what line, as your source code has multiple calls to By.id, some of them use output of another method as argument?

Answer (score 1):

Since your `getUserNameLocator()` method returns a `By` type object and `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated()` method receives a `By` type value, you can use that inside `isLoaded()` method as following:

```java
public boolean isLoaded(){

    return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(getUserNameLocator())).isDisplayed();

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly what I did and it worked. Thanks a million.!